# How can I turn off the screen in the android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.3-gingerbread

How can I turn off the screen in the android emulator?

I am using android 2.3.3 version

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to press F7, which is the same as pressing the power button. Here is a complete list of shortcuts: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#controlling

Comment: F7 works. And also a button in right menu (if available) that looks like a round turn-off button works. Maybe you should press it twice.

Comment: This crashes the emulator (Segmentation Fault error) on an API 23 emulator with x86 system image on Fedora 23. Other keyboard commands work just fine.

Comment: For OSX - the answer of @Patrick Boos was unfortunately deleted - F7 did not work, however this does: `adb shell input keyevent 26`